# How can you clean your coordinates in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove any coordinates from my dataset that fall outside of the state of Utah.

Is there a good package to utilize for this?

Answer (score -1):

you could use something like :

```
data <- data[state != 'Utah']
```

Else you could use this package : dplyr dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html